# Truffle contract name different from filename causes error in test

Tags: contract-development, truffle

I'm trying to use Truffle to deploy/test a cluster of interrelated contracts that call each other.

When I run "truffle migrate" all of the contracts get deployed successfully and the transactions show up in Ganache, but Truffle doesn't seem to have any conception of some of them when I use ".deployed()" in the console or in other migrations; however, the first 2 contracts do show up.

EDIT: The problematic contracts are **not** all derived from the same base contract; I just tried it with an empty contract (just an empty constructor) and the same thing happened to it.

Answer (score 1):

Few things you could check on

1. Have one file per contract.
2. Make sure you contract name and .sol file name are the same for problematic contracts ( contract HelloWorld, in file HelloWorld.sol).
3. Make sure you have *import* relevant dependency files in each contract file
4. Deleting build folder (which get created when compile) also resolve some inconsistency problems occur specially during the testing phase.

Comment: 1. I've ensured this in all my code; I am using a fork of someone else's code for one of the two contracts that are recognized by Truffle; one file in there has two contracts in a file.
2. I've checked this.
3. The contracts compile and deploy fine in Remix, as well as in Truffle; it's just that Truffle doesn't keep their addresses and thinks they aren't deployed.
4. I've tried doing this.